# Calculate the following integral in the rectangle $[0,1]$x$[1,2]$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

I have to calculate the following integral: $\int_0^1 \int_1^2 \frac{ln(x+y)}{(x+y)^3} dxdy$

Any help? I don't know how to separate the variables.

Comment: Make the change of variables $z= x+y, dz = dx$ and compute $$\int_0^1\int_{1+y}^{2+y} \frac{\ln(z)}{z^3} dz dy,$$ where integration by parts might help you with the inner integral.

Comment: So am I considering $y$ as a constant?

Comment: Yes, indeed. This is how one computes iterated integrals. In the inner integral you consider $y$ as fixed and compute the integral with respect to $x$. This then yields a function in $y$ which you have to integrate in $y$.

Comment: Thank you, so it is the same logic even if I have $xy$?

Comment: Yes, it is completely irrelevant what the precise form is.